# References in Chapter Titles

Tags: header-footer, cross-referencing, chapters

I am currently writing a manuscript using `\documentclass{book}`.  I would like to devote one of the chapters in the manuscript to a proof of an earlier result.  I have named the Chapter:

```
\chapter{Proof of Theorem \ref{Theorem1}}
```

and the actual chapter itself (including the chapter name in the table of contents and the chapter title) looks fine.  I have include an image below.

[image]

However, in the even numbered pages of the chapter at the top right-hand side of the page is an all-capitalized version of the chapter title, and the reference there does not seem to go through:

[image]

I have compiled the code multiple times, so I am sure it is not a compiling error.  Is there any way I can keep the Theorem reference in the title and have it properly show up at the top of the even pages of the chapter?

Comment: It seems like you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), correct? If so, is it necessary for the links to be hyperlinked?

Comment: @Werner: I am indeed using hyperref.  It is not necessary to have hyperlinks, although I much prefer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i believe (but am unable to check) that when the chapter title is upper cased for the running head, the name specified with `\ref` is also uppercased.  this will not match the original label.

make this label "THEOREM1" instead of "Theorem1" and all should be resolved.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks for the simple fix.

Answer (score 4):

The following option uses [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to extract the reference number, but you lose hyperlinking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{hyperref,refcount}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapter.\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Proofs of Theorem~\getrefnumber{Theorem1}}
\begin{theorem}\label{Theorem1}
An important theorem.
\end{theorem}
\newpage
Some text.
\end{document}
```

So, instead of using `\ref{Theorem1}`, you would use `\getrefnumber{Theorem1}`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is partly caused by what I believe is a major flaw in the standard classes, that is applying `\MakeUppercase` to the titles as part of the definition of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`, whereas it should be, if desired, applied when typesetting the headers.

However, changing this is not sufficient because `\MakeUppercase` would capitalize also the label before computing the reference. The package `textcase` could come to the rescue, but, alas, `hyperref` redefines `\ref` with `\DeclareRobustCommand` so what's seen by `\MakeTextUppercase` is not `\ref` (which the macro knows how to handle), but `\ref•` (where the bullet represents a space in the name): the first level expansion of `\foo` after

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{...}
```

is indeed `\protect\foo•`. This first level expansion happens because the title is passed through `\protected@edef`.

Here's a possible solution, which

1. modifies the `headings` page style definition in order to exchange the place where the uppercasing is performed;
2. uses `textcase` for the uppercasing macros
3. modifies the definition of `\ref` with the help of `etoolbox` so that it becomes a `\protected` macro which survives `\protected@edef` unchanged.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% modify \ps@headings so the uppercasing is done at the right place
\def\ps@headings{%
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\MakeTextUppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\MakeTextUppercase{\rightmark}}\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}%
   }%
 \def\sectionmark##1{%
   \markright{%
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
       \thesection. \ %
     \fi
     ##1}%
  }%
}
% issue again the style declaration to renew it
\pagestyle{headings}
\makeatother
% modify \ref to become \protected; it needs to be done
% \AtBeginDocument because hyperref delays its redefinitions
\AtBeginDocument{\robustify{\ref}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Proof of Theorem \ref{theorem1}}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem1}
An important theorem.
\end{theorem}

\newpage

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you please upgrade this to avoid uppercasing math?  it's impossible to persuade authors that they shouldn't put math in titles, so that's the only possible fallback for some of us.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Doesn't `\MakeTextUppercase` take care of it?

Comment: oh, yes it does.  (i'm still not awake enough to see the difference between the text at the top and the code.)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a demonstration of barbara beeton's answer. It does not break hyperlinking.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Proof of Theorem \ref{THEOREM1}}
\begin{theorem}\label{THEOREM1}
An important theorem.
\end{theorem}
\newpage
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked header]

Comment: thanks.  (i would have been quite happy for you to edit my answer. this is a nice concise demonstration,  anyhow, +1)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wouldn't like to do that ;). I wouldn't know whether to use capitals or not ;).