# Appendix header and references in sections

Tags: header-footer, cross-referencing, appendices

I am trying to use Appendix for some proofs in the thesis. The appendix looks like this:

```
\chapter{Proofs for Chapter ABC}

\section{Proof of \thmref{thm:some_theorem}}
```

While the "Proofs for Chapter ABC" shows up correctly, the proof section seems to mess up the appendix header (see image). I double checked and the reference is correct. Any reason why it might be the case ?

[image: Appendix header]

Comment: Did you remember to compile twice?

Comment: Its rather complicated TeX file so it may take me a while before I can produce a small example.

Comment: I have noticed one thing, disabling hyperref package seems to fix the problem.

Comment: this looks like the same problem described in [References in Chapter Titles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171864/579), namely a lowercase label and an automatically uppercased heading.

Comment: Thanks !! That was exactly the case for me. I used the \getrefnumber solution.